# Relation between controller,view and model in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

please see the below image.
[image]

i often seen the below picture is used to show the relation between controller,view and model in asp.net mvc project. i do not know much about asp.net MVC but still i guess first request is process by controller and controller gets data from model and push that data to view by controller just to populate the view.

if anyone see the below image then probably notice that view can interact with model but that is not true. why people use the image for showing the relationship for mvc. if the above image is right so anyone please tell me how view can pass any info to model directly with taking any help from controller. please explain what the image is trying to say in details. thanks

Comment: it shows that View is binded with model so View is passed Model so they are linked this way

Comment: Yes, but why we don't have the link in other direction too, from model to view, because when we change model it affects view, too ?

Comment: I think  view can see its model and you can change model in view after controller passed it to view.

Comment: if you ignore controller how can you pass model to view? Or how can find out wich view must generate for user request?

Comment: @Dejo Model is used in View, View cannot be used in Model

Comment: please some one discuss this topic with sample code to understand the relation and flow between view,model and controller. thanks

Comment: @Mou there is alot of stuff on web

Comment: @EhsanSajjad : u said "View is passed Model so they are linked this way" i really do not understand what u r trying to say. so please come example. thanks

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: hook me to few relevant write up

Comment: consider this for example:http://geekswithblogs.net/dlussier/archive/2009/11/21/136454.aspx

Comment: Perhaps think of it like this: The Model is an object in it's own right and usually represents something like a database table. The Controller handles the Model and what happens to it (with the database, passing it to other controllers & views etc) and the View is 'loaned' the Model by the controller for user interaction (usually via a form or just to display on screen)